# KQL group by with same result as the drag and drop group feature

Tags: azure, azure-diagnostics, azure-log-analytics, kql

When using the Monitor, Log feature in Azure Portal you can group rows by dragging and dropping a column header into a certain box, the problem is that this is not saved when pressing the save button.

How do I write KQL that generates the same result? Summarize by Column_Name doesn't yield the same result.

Comment: can you add some screenshots?

Answer (score 4):

Save functionality only saves the query editor content and doesn't save anything within the results pane. I believe that using pack and make-set operators can generate a very close output to what you are looking for (if I understood it correctly). See below an example for grouping by client_OS and an internal breakdown by name and count

```
customEvents
| summarize count() by name, client_OS
| extend p =pack('name', name, 'count', count_) 
| summarize names = make_set(p)  by client_OS
```

Comment: This kind of works, though the resulting nest is 3-4 layers deep rather than the concise single layer result when using the GUI and `Group columns`. Really wish there was an easy way to display this natively with KQL.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the closest to what you expect can be achieved this way:

```
exceptions
| summarize entries = make_list(pack_all()) by operation_Name
```

Scalar function `pack_all` creates an object from all available columns and aggregation function `make_list` returns JSON array of all the values provided as its arguments.

**Edit:** The `makelist` function is deprecated, use `make_list` instead.

Comment: This seems to max out at 127 results per `entries` value.

Comment: @ericOnline If you use `make_list` instead of the deprecated `makelist` there will be no such a limit. I have edited my answer. You can read more about this in the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/makelist-aggfunction).